Access website's localStorage from the chrome extension
I already have a website which records the screen and based on if you're logged in or out you can extend the recording time. Now I'm kinda developing the same logic in the chrome extension but I want to access the website's localStorage to get the profile and check if user is logged in or no because I want the user to have the same accessibilities they have in the website e.g. the max. recording time etc...
I'm using manifest v3
So I was wondering if there's a way to access it without opening a tab?
If you need more info I'm here, Thank you!
I already tried opening the tab when we load the extension but I dont think it's a really good user experience, and also saw somewhere that if a user is using an adblocker then things might not work with this solution.
